# How do you start using MLflow SQL storage instead of the file system storage?

Tags: mlflow

If I were getting started with MLflow, then how would I set up a database store? Is it sufficient to create a new MySQL database or a SQLite database and point MLflow to that?

I tried to set the tracking URI, but that didn't create a database if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

**How to set up MLFlow properly**

**pip install the following:**

```
PyMySQL==0.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
werkzeug==2.0.3
mlflow
mlflow[extras]==1.14.1
```

**Set up the artifact dir:**

```
mkdir -p mlflow/artifacts
chmod -R 1777  mlflow
```

**This will run a detached process in cli using SQLLite:**

```
mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.sqlite.db --default-artifact-root './mlflow/artifacts' </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

You will then be able to see the UI, fully functioning, at:
`http://{{server_ip or localhost}}:5000` - If you are on a server you may have to expose the port like `ufw allow 5000/tcp`, or however your cloud provider wants you to do it.

*Check my answer here to shut a detached mlflow process down:*
[How to safely shutdown mlflow ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531166/how-to-safely-shutdown-mlflow-ui/65692072#65692072)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create database by yourself. Mlflow creates tables automatically based on defined schema. It has no control over databases.